# Can I use app with real users or "Can only call this method on valid test users for your app"

Tags: exception, testing, facebook-graph-api

I am developing desktop app and it should post some info to user's facebook wall.
Everything is ok: authorization, token, etc

But after I send POST request, I get error: "Can only call this method on valid test users for your app".

So, assume that development is finished and I'd like to use app in real world.
And first, I'd like to test app with my OWN account. But I cant, because I get "Can only call this method on valid test users for your app". Should you change any options for my facebook app?

I have check every link from Google related to this topic, but no result.

SHORTLY: What I have to do when I dont need test users anymore and I want to use app with any account including my OWN account?

Thanks.

Comment: I cant use it with ANY real user. Is it FB issue or my issue???

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm looking for it as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{AppId}/advanced`
2. Set Sandbox Mode to `Disabled`.
3. Also ensure you clear out any whitelisting settings you have for your app

Comment: Sandbox is disabled, server whitelist and other fields are blank. Right now I have exception: connection closed by server. Seems FB has problems :) Will try again later...

Comment: No, it doesnt work...still revieve "Can only call this method on valid test users for your app"

Comment: DMCS why wast time pointing people to articles on how to accept answers. If you would read the comment you would see that it didn't help.

Comment: Many people will only try the 1st thing mentioned and say it still doesn't work. Many times, a simple question like this will prod the questioner in taking the additional steps and really finding the answer to their issue might be, rather than calling them out by asking questions like: "Did you really do all three things, prove it to me?".